# How does python's `in` function work when it triggers via `__getitem__()`'?

Tags: python, membership

[The official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) indicates that python first tries to check via `__contains__()`, then `__iter__()`, and finally `__getitem__()`, depending on which function is defined, in order to resolve an `in` call.
Eg:

```
if y in x:
    print("y present in x")
else:
    print("y not present in x")
```

The linked documentation indicates that if there exists any non negative index `i` such that `x[i] == y`, then the result is `True` else `False`.
How does it perform a search over all such `i`? A linear traversal over 'all' positive numbers seems out of the question. There must be some bounds in which the linear traversal happens (for lists, it should be 0 to len()). How are those bounds determined?

Comment: For regular lists/sequences, that's exactly what happens - Python goes through each of their elements attempting to equate them with the search element.

Comment: @zwer There the `__contains__` is explicitly defined, so the question doesn't arise.

Comment: What's the alternative to a linear traversal? Magic?

Comment: @moooeeeep I was referring to https://github.com/bslatkin/effectivepython/blob/master/example_code/item_28.py when the question arose in my mind. See `class IndexableNode` on the page.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the section starting: _"Lastly, the old-style iteration protocol is tried..."_ ? Maybe add that to the post, then...

Comment: Then I don't understand what are you asking. You have either an option to implement your `__contains__()` and do the comparison yourself (i.e. via a hash table or whatever works best for your container data) or let Python iterate over it, grabbing each element along the way with `__getitem__()` and comparing it with the search element. Sure, you can optimize some structures for faster searching/retrieval, but you can't escape the linear iteration in that case.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I suspect there 'must' be a `len()` implentation for the said class so that `__getitem__()` can be run from `0` to `len()`. But it works without that. A linear traversal from 0 to the largest possible positive index seems implausible.

Comment: @zwer I'm asking if the linear traversal is within some bounds or from 0 to positive infinity. If bounds, how will it figure the bounds?

Comment: It starts with `0` and keeps adding `1` until it finds the item or gets an `IndexError`.  If it ever gets an `IndexError` it stops and returns `False`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yes that makes sense! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aaah, I think get it... You want to know how the *key* is obtained to iterate over all elements on custom containers that do not have neither `__contains__()` nor `__iter__()` - simple, it works exactly using linear iteration until [`IndexError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError) is encountered, as stated in the documentation:

> ... if a class defines `__getitem__()`, `x in y` is `True` if and only if there is a non-negative integer index `i` such that `x == y[i]`, and **all lower integer indices do not raise `IndexError` exception. (If any other exception is raised, it is as if in raised that exception)**.

Case in point:

```
class CustomClass(object):

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if item > 20:  # lets force the break so that it doesn't go to sys.maxsize
            raise IndexError()
        print(item)  # print the item requested
        # implied: return None so it doesn't match 5

result = 5 in CustomClass()  # this will keep printing numbers until 20
```

Comment: Yeah, that statement wasn't on its own clear to me. Now that you point it, I look dumb :(

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of these special methods is to give *you*, the designer of your data structure, a way to perform lookups in a fast way that is appropriate to your situation. For example, you could derive a class from `list` that is enhanced by a reverse index for fast lookup by value. (Obviously this would slow down insertion since the index needs to be updated, but let's assume that you'll be doing a lot of lookups so you know it's worth it.)

If your class has no way to improve on the default access, you don't need to define the special methods. Python will fall back on whatever is available, including sequential search.

Answer (score 1):

> How does it perform a search over all such `i`?

This depends, pretty much on the data structure of the object in which the search is performing on. For example if you have a `list` object, the complexity of membership checking is O(n) and if you have a data structure that uses hashtable accessing its items (the `__getitem__` attribute) such as dictionary or set the complexity is approximately O(1).

So in general for user defined objects it works as it's explained in documentation. For objects without hash table it's a linear search and for objects with hash table its a constant search.

Answer (score 1):

The iteration for objects without `__contains__` or `__iter__` occurs [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/48ed88a93bb0bbeaae9a4cfaa533e4edf13bcb51/Objects/iterobject.c#L48). The sequence scan occurs [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a6fdddb7df00aefad2ec6e362dbf10d4bd8bff32/Objects/abstract.c#L1969). The decision to use `__contains__` or falling back on iteration occurs [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/48ed88a93bb0bbeaae9a4cfaa533e4edf13bcb51/Objects/abstract.c#L2061).

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly how it works. Here's a demonstration using `list`:

```
$ for a in `seq 6`; do python3 -m timeit -s "a = 10**$a" 'a in list(range(a))'; done
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.84 usec per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.04 usec per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 57.7 usec per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 639 usec per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 6.74 msec per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 70.3 msec per loop
```

You can observe the time complexity increasing proportional to the size of the container.

Comment: But the question is not for lists since `__contains__` is explicitly defined for lists. Its for custom classes.